# how to set background color for selected position in listview in activity

Tags: android, background-color

> if (rsSetup1.next()) {
>                                         ItemsBean bean1 = new ItemsBean();
>
> ```
>                                       bean1.setLinenum(rsSetup1.getInt("Line_No"));
>                                       bean1.setProdnum(rsSetup1.getInt("ItemName"));
>
>                                       bean1.setDeleteFlag(rsSetup1.getInt("DeleteFlag"));
>                                   disablelist.add(bean1);
>
>
>
>                               }
>
>                               CustomAdapter adapter1 = new CustomAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this, itemsList1);
>                                   for(int i=0;i<itemsList1.size();i++)
>                                   {
>                                       for(int j=0;j<disablelist.size();j++)
>                                       {
>                                       if(itemsList1.get(i).getProdnum()==disablelist.get(j).getProdnum())
>                                       {
>
>                                           itemsList1.get(i).setSelection(true);
>
>
>
>
>                                       }
> ```

As am new to android i was suffering a lot due to issues ,here in this i got the position of list view

itemsList1.get(i).setSelection(true);

then how to chnage the  back ground color for that position . please any one help me

Activity:

if (listView == listView1) {

```
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this, itemsList1);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);


            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            listView1.setOnTouchListener(new AdapterView.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                     newListitems2.clear();
                  newListitems2.addAll(itemsList1);

                         dialog = new Dialog(PendingOrdersActitvity.this);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.itembumping);

                        dialog.show();




                        list1=(ListView )dialog.findViewById(R.id.list1);

                        ItemBumpingAdapter adapter2 = new ItemBumpingAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this,newListitems2);
                        list1.setAdapter(adapter2);


            Button okButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok1);
                        okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            Connection con1 = DbHandler.dbConnection();
                                try{
                                PreparedStatement stmt1 = con1
                                        .prepareStatement("Select Line_No, ItemName,DeleteFlag from PendingOrders_Dtl where Inv_No=? ");

                                stmt1.setString(1,invNo);
                                ResultSet rsSetup1 = stmt1.executeQuery();


                                if (rsSetup1.next()) {
                                    ItemsBean bean1 = new ItemsBean();


                                        bean1.setLinenum(rsSetup1.getInt("Line_No"));
                                        bean1.setProdnum(rsSetup1.getInt("ItemName"));

                                        bean1.setDeleteFlag(rsSetup1.getInt("DeleteFlag"));
                                    disablelist.add(bean1);



                                }

                                CustomAdapter adapter1 = new CustomAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this, itemsList1);
                                    for(int i=0;i<itemsList1.size();i++)
                                    {
                                        for(int j=0;j<disablelist.size();j++)
                                        {
                                        if(itemsList1.get(i).getProdnum()==disablelist.get(j).getProdnum())
                                        {


            });
```

main list adapter:

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater inflator;
ArrayList<ItemsBean> newList = new ArrayList<ItemsBean>();

ArrayList<String> childList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> qtychildList = new ArrayList<String>();
String parentobjid=null;

PendingOrdersActitvity myactivity;
public CustomAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity kdsActitvity,
        ArrayList<ItemsBean> invoiceDataList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.ctx = kdsActitvity;


    this.newList = invoiceDataList;
    this.inflator = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return newList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView qty, name, childText, qtyChild;

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    String item = null, qty = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.invoicelistadapter, null);
        holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        holder.childText = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.childitem);
        holder.qtyChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.qtychild);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    parentobjid=newList.get(position).getParentobjectid();
    if(!parentobjid.isEmpty())
    {
        holder.name.setText("   " +newList.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
        holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
        holder.qty.setText("      "+String.valueOf(newList.get(position)
                .getQuantityDisplay()));
        holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));

    }
    else
    {

    holder.name.setText(newList.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
    holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newList.get(position)
            .getQuantityDisplay()));
    holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

    }
```

Popup list adapter :

```
public ItemBumpingAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity itemActitvity,
        ArrayList<ItemsBean> newList1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.ctx=itemActitvity;
    this.newListitems = newList1;
    this.inflator = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return newListitems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


public class ViewHolder {
    TextView qty, name, childText, qtyChild;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    Button btn;
}
@Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                final ViewHolder holder;
                String item = null, qty = null;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.itembumpingadapter, null);
                    holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
                    holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
                    holder.childText = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.childitem);
                    holder.qtyChild = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.qtychild);
                     holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chckbox1);


                    convertView.setTag(holder);



                } else {

                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                parentobjid=newListitems.get(position).getParentobjectid();
                if(!parentobjid.isEmpty())
                {
                    holder.name.setText("   " +newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
                    holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
                    holder.qty.setText("      "+String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position)
                            .getQuantityDisplay()));
                    holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
                }
                else
                {

                holder.name.setText(newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
                holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position)
                        .getQuantityDisplay()));
                holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(newListitems.get(position).isChecked() );

                holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
                holder.checkbox.setTag(position);

        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {


                        int position=(Integer)buttonView.getTag();


                          newListitems.get(position).setChecked(!newListitems.get(position).isChecked());
                          if(newListitems.get(position).isChecked()){


                              for (int i = 0; i <newListitems.size(); i++) {
                                  if(i == position){ 
                                      ItemsBean bean=new ItemsBean();
                                      bean.setInvNo(newListitems.get(position).getInvNo());
                                      bean.setItemnNameDisplay(newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
                                      bean.setLinenum(newListitems.get(position).getLinenum());
                                      bean.setQuantityDisplay(newListitems.get(position).getQuantityDisplay());
                                      bean.setProdnum(newListitems.get(position).getProdnum());
                                      bean.setFlag(1);
                                      bean.setCount(1);
                                      newListitems1.add(bean);

                                  }

                              }


                              PendingOrdersActitvity.getInstance().insertintodatabase(newListitems1);

                              newListitems1.clear();

                          }



                    }
                });



                  if(newListitems.get(position).isChecked()){
                         for (int i = 0; i <newListitems.size(); i++) {
                             if(i == position){ 
                             convertView .setEnabled(false);
                                convertView .setClickable(false);
                                 convertView .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DCDBDB"));
```

Answer (score 0):

eg:-  `itemsList1.get(i).setBackgroundColor(color.black);`

Comment: set background color is not coming in thsat

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(items.get(i).isSelected()){
                    view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.black));
                }else{
                    view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.blue));
                }
```

Comment: view wont come because it written in activity not adapterr class

Comment: you can get view when you click on item of listview like below in activity.
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                
            }
        });

Comment: actually it must not be clicked, when get position automatoically color has to change

Comment: Then you have to write
if(items.get(i).isSelected()){
                    view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.black));
                }else{
                    view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.blue));
                }
code at your adapter where you bind all value in view. And in above code view is our layout object which you bind in list.

Comment: actually i have a list view when i click on the list view i will get popup window contaning same items as main list . the popup window contains check box , when i click on check box and press ok i have change background color of same item in main list

Comment: Then in ArrayList you have do setSelection(true) for the position which you click on checkBox.
then just do adapter. notifyDataSetChanged(). But before that you have to write above given code in your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

To hold the color of listview item when you press it, include the following line in your listview layout:

```
android:background="@drawable/list_bgk"
```

Then define list_bgk.xml in drawable folder like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/pressed_color"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

Finally, include this in your ListView onClickListener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
        view.setSelected(true);
        ... //Anything
    }
});
```

This way, only one item will be color-selected at any time. You can define your color values in res/values/colors.xml with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="pressed_color">#4d90fe</color>
    <color name="default_color">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: i wont click or press item by getting position it must be automatically change